# byte is displayed instead of actual pdf file in webApi

Tags: c#, api, pdf

I try to display a pdf file that is being generated in the API but the browser display the actual bytes instead of the actual pdf file. Why is that?

```
        public ActionResult Preview()
    {

    var pdfBytes =  p.GeneratePreview();
            using (MemoryStream pdfStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                pdfStream.Write(pdfBytes, 0, pdfBytes.Length);
                pdfStream.Position = 0;
                return new FileStreamResult(pdfStream, "application/pdf");
            }
}
```

Comment: Don't wrap `pdfStream` with `using` statement in this case. `FileStreamResult` will dispose your stream when response will be sent to your user.

Comment: also you can create your `MemoryStream` just like this: `var pdfStream = new MemoryStream(pdfBytes);`

Comment: Should this work...?             
var pdfStream = new MemoryStream(pdfBytes);
            return new FileStreamResult(pdfStream, "application/pdf");
Beacuse this also give me bytes in browser

Comment: You may also try to add `Content-Disposition` with value `inline; filename="filename.pdf"` header to your response

Comment: Like this ? Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline; filename=filename.pdf"); in my WebApi project I get "Cannot resolve Response" error when trying that.